# Stored procedure for monthly sales with discount

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, accounting

I need advice on how to create a stored procedure, or many stored procedures for generating a *monthly sales report* in our company. I have shortened the tables down to make it more easy to understand:

We have two tables:

- `ITEM_SALES`, which consists of:

  ```
      Item_ID
      Name
      Store
      Sales_Date
      Sales_Price
      Quantity
  ```
- And `ITEM_DISCOUNT`, which consists of:

  ```
      Item_ID
      Name
      Store
      Sales_Price
      Date_From
      Date_To
  ```

Explanation: After each month, our different stores will send us a report on which discounts they had. These discounts can vary from one, to many days and therefor we have the Date_From, Date_to.

My idea: To make this sales report, i need a procedure that first fetches all sales in `ITEM_SALES`, then checks all the discounts in `ITEM_DISCOUNT` and overwrites the ones that have similar `Item_ID`, `Name`, and `Store` for a selected period.

Example: So if a item originally had a sales_price on 99,- and then had a discount sales_price to 79,- for 2014-01-02 to 2014-01-10 it has to be overwritten for that period so the report shows the right numbers.

Is this understandable? And can anyone help me or give me some tips on the way? Is temporary tables good for this?

If more info is needed, I will provide!

Comment: you're asking for SQL - I think this is relatively easy to solve in MySQL but I'm not sure if the solution would be pure SQL99.  Would you like to see it?

Comment: Yes please, that would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the report by using `LEFT JOIN` within a Stored Procedure where month and year for which report is needed, can be passed as parameter as below:

SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSalesReport 
   @month INT, 
   @year  INT 
AS 
  SELECT isa.Item_ID,
         isa.Name,
         isa.Store,
         isa.Sales_Date,
         COALESCE(id.Sales_Price, isa.Sales_Price) AS SalesPrice,
         isa.Quantity
       FROM ITEM_SALES AS isa
       LEFT JOIN ITEM_DISCOUNT AS id
       ON  isa.Item_ID = id.Item_ID
       AND isa.Name = id.Name
       AND isa.Store = id.Store
       AND isa.Sales_Date BETWEEN id.Date_From AND id.Date_To 
       WHERE MONTH(isa.Sales_Date) = @month AND YEAR(isa.Sales_Date) = @year
```

Comment: This is getting all the sales

Comment: do you want a report of current month?

Comment: This seems to be going the right direction to me.  @DipenduPaul, I thought you _wanted_ all the sales?

Comment: I want to be able to choose month

Comment: Sorry i thought i tagged it, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 ;)

Comment: I have updated my Answer...see if this gives you resultset you are looking for

Comment: I did some modifications to it, but i cant seem to get the Date to work. It just fetches all sales data.

Comment: There was a bug in the query,  MONTH(isa.Sales_Date) = @month AND YEAR(isa.Sales_Date) = @year should be a part of `WHERE` statement and not `ON`. Please make this change and let me know if its working fine now.

Comment: Hey Paul, i fixed the bug you wrote. I am still not getting any sales from the Discount table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49218/discussion-between-dipendu-paul-and-lebowski)